# XPath expression in xsl file does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt, xpath

I have an XPath expression that work fine in Firefox, but when I’m viewing the file in IE I got an error. Is there a work-around to let IE understand my expression?

My XSL (I removed a lot so it’s a bit easier to see).

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" >
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>
     <xsl:value-of select="versions/project" />
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
     ...
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="content">
     
        <xsl:for-each select="/releasenotes/notes/note[component/@type=$unitTag]">
         <xsl:for-each select=".[component/@number=$versionNumber and text/@type='new']">
          <li type="disc">
           <xsl:value-of select="text" />
           <xsl:for-each select="component[not(@type=$unitTag)]">
            <xsl:sort select="@type" order="ascending"/>
            , <a href="#{@type}_{@number}">
             <xsl:variable name="unitType" select="@type"/>
             <xsl:value-of select="//components/component[tag=$unitType]/name" />&#160;(<xsl:value-of select="@number" />)
            </a>
           </xsl:for-each>
          </li>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
       
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
     
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".[component/@number=$versionNumber and text/@type='new']">
```

Resulting in this error:

```
Expected token 'EOF' found '['. .-->[<--component/@number='$versionNumber' and text/@type='new']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="/releasenotes/notes/note[component/@type=$unitTag]">
    <xsl:for-each select=".[component/@number=$versionNumber and text/@type='new']">
```

it seems you simply want

```
<xsl:for-each select="/releasenotes/notes/note[component/@type=$unitTag][component/@number=$versionNumber and text/@type='new']">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="/releasenotes/notes/note[component/@type=$unitTag and component/@number=$versionNumber and text/@type='new']">
```

Answer (score 1):

For workaround, try to replace that particular `.` with the equivalent, unabbreviated expression, `self::node()` to make the XSL works across browsers. Related recent question regarding predicate after abbreviated step (`.` and `..`) in XPath: [Selenium WebDriver Xpath current element attribute reports invalid Xpath exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999535/selenium-webdriver-xpath-current-element-attribute-reports-invalid-xpath-excepti/44014864#44014864)

Answer (score 1):

`.[condition]` is not allowed by the XPath 1.0 grammar, so IE is correct to reject it.

You could actually replace the

```
<xsl:for-each select=".[condition]">
```

with

```
<xsl:if test="condition">
```

or combine it into the parent `xsl:for-each` as suggested by Martin Honnen.